# Is it possible to successfully encrypt/decrypt in DUKPT using different sized BDKs?

Tags: block-cipher, keys, key-size

We are having our P2PE Solution validated against the PCI P2PE standard.  We currently use a TDEA 2-key based BDK, and IPEK in both the encryption and decryption environments.  ANSI X9.24-1 (2009) states that the BDK can be either 2-key or 3-key and the QSA is insisting that the BDK must be TDEA 3-key as per Appendix C in the standard. Our encryption environment can't perform encryption using TDEA 3-key (hardware limitation).  The assessor has asserted that mixed sizes of BDKs can be used with DUKPT, based on his reading of ANSI X9.24-1 (2009). Is that true?  Can DUKPT encrypt plaintext with an IPEK derived from a 2-key BDK and successfully decrypt that data from that same IPEK in a decryption environment with a 3-key BDK?

Comment: More information is needed. Specifically which standard is the QSA referencing Appendix C from: PCI P2PE or ANSI X9.24-1 (2009)? Exactly what is the wording in the section. Note: my QSA sees no reason that what you want to do is not allowed-barring more information.

Comment: The QSA is referring to the table in P2PE v2.0 r1.1 Appendix C. That table emphatically states that TDEA keys used in a P2PE solution must be 3-length (168 effective bits) if those keys reside outside a POI device.  Inside of a POI device, the keys can be 2-length (112 effective bits)

Comment: The QSA is referring to the table in P2PE v2.0 r1.1 Appendix C. That table emphatically states that TDEA keys used in a P2PE solution must be triple-length (168 effective bits) if those keys reside outside a POI device.  Inside of a POI device, the keys can be double-length (112 effective bits).  I think I was misinformed about the concern.  The concern lies with the IPEK.  How is it possible to generate a double length IPEK from a triple length BDK and a double length KSN?  ANSI X9.24-1 (2009) gives examples of IPEK generation using double length BDKs only.

Answer (score 2):

As this is symmetric key encryption the key used to encrypt the data must be used to decrypt the data so if a double-length TDES key encrypted the data, the same double-length TDES key can decrypt the data. A triple-length TDES key cannot decrypt data encrypted by a double-length TDES key and vice versa.

The P2PE requires that the minimum length for a TDES key be triple-length, i.e. 192-bits (168-bit excluding parity). However, if implemented as part of a DUKPT key management scheme, the TDES keys may be double-length. This is detailed in the footnotes of Appendix C.